# How to work correctly with the code of my application within the then of a Promise?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am developing an application
web using Angular2. I'm using Firebase Realtime Database.

For the entity *'arbitro'*, I have implemented two classes:

**arbitro.component.ts**, which manages the logic of the entity and the associated screen

**arbitro.service.ts**, which executes the operations on the database.

In the *service* class, I have implemented the following method, which executes an **update** on the node of the parameter in the database, and returns an element of type ***Promise***.

```
editArbitro(arbitro: Arbitro) {
    return this.items.update(arbitro.id, arbitro);
  }
```

In the *component* class (from where I call the **update**), I have implemented the method shown below. The **update** of the *service* is called, and then I work with the returned ***Promise***, using the *then* and *catch* clauses.

```
this.promise = this.arbitroSvc.editArbitro(this.arbitro);
        this.promise.then(function () {
          console.log('Update completed successfully');
          this.checkEdited = true;
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log('Update failed: ' + error);
          });
```

- *ArbitroSvc* is an instance of arbitro.service.ts.
- *promise* is an attribute of the component class.
- *checkEdited* is a boolean attribute, which I want to assign true if the ***Promise*** throws a successful response.

When I launch the application and execute the **update**, I get the following response in the console:

> Update completed successfully.
>
> Update failed: TypeError: Cannot set property 'checkEdited' of undefined

Analyzing the output, I deduce that the **update** was executed successfully, and the problem is in the assignment of the value to checkEdited.

From this, I have two questions about the operation and implementation of this logic:

- Is the way I manage the **update** response within my *component* class correct?
- If it is correct, what is the error that I get about the *checkEdited* and how can I avoid it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is with the binding of `this`. Inside an inner function, it refers to a different value.

Three options you have are:

1. Use an arrow function, which captures the surrounding `this`:

```
this.promise = this.arbitroSvc.editArbitro(this.arbitro);
this.promise.then(() => {
    console.log('Update completed successfully');
    this.checkEdited = true;
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Update failed: ' + error);
});
```

2. Assign `this` to a temporary variable (e.g. `self`):

```
let self = this;
this.promise = this.arbitroSvc.editArbitro(this.arbitro);
this.promise.then(() => {
    console.log('Update completed successfully');
    self.checkEdited = true;
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Update failed: ' + error);
});
```

3. Bind the inner function:

```
this.promise = this.arbitroSvc.editArbitro(this.arbitro);
this.promise.then(() => {
    console.log('Update completed successfully');
    this.checkEdited = true;
}.bind(this)).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Update failed: ' + error);
});
```